# I got this error in Python, EnvironmentNotWritable Error

Tags: python, anaconda

I ran 'conda install pandas-datareader' in Python to get the data. 
A EnvironmentNotWritable Error has appeared, as shown below.
I suspect it is due to the (read only) option in base environment, but I do not know how to fix it.

I have just started Python and have little knowledge. I hope you can help me.

I do not know if it's necessary, but the version is like this.

```
active environment : None
conda version : 4.6.11
conda-build version : 3.17.8
python version : 3.7.3.final.0
base environment : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3 (read only)
```

i ran this code

```
conda install pandas-datareader
```

During the installation of the package, the following error message appears.

```
....
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed

EnvironmentNotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to the target environment.
  environment location: C\ProgramData\Anaconda3
```

Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

Comment: Try running the console in admin mode.

Answer (score 1):

There can be two simple issues due to which this issue is generated--
* During installing library your Anaconda program is running. This restricts you to make any changes in environment during working.

Solution-1 Close Anaconda program then try installing library on command prompt.
Solution-2 Close Anaconda program then run Anaconda Prompt as Administrator.

I Hope this will work for you.

Comment: please elaborate more on: 1. how to run anaconda prompt as Administrator; 2. How to install library on command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the environments tab in the Anaconda if the problem persists after you run it with administrative privileges. in the Environments tab you can create new Environments, just hit create. For example, I created special environment for Rstudio. Whatever you like.

P.S. I checked conda install pandas-datareader on the fresh Anaconda installation and it works. So double check the Environments tab what you have there and install it with administrative rights.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm replying very early to your question, but still the solution that worked for me is to just run your anaconda prompt in administrator mode.